# Controller to View Flow Without scala.html

Tags: java, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap, playframework

my action returns a jsonNode via Json.toJson(dataArr)

Googling shows that one way I can handle this json response and view it in my html and bootstrap css is by using AJAX via JSON.parse(jsonStr).  How do I use the jsonNode my action returns as jsonStr so that I can parse the json and view response data in my browser?  Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like strictly a javascript question, but we need more information as to what you want to do with that json response. Are you displaying a simple message, a table of data, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

How about (in Scala)

```
def myAction = Action {
    Ok(Json.toJson(jsonNode))    
}
```

Source: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonRequests.

Or the Java version: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJsonRequests